# I have the following list of strings yet I want to apply filter so that I may certain item from the lists.How to do that?

Tags: list, web-scraping, filter, beautifulsoup, python-3.6

I am trying to obtain the image data from the following [website](https://www.ikea.com/sa/en/catalog/products/00361049/).

However, I am getting a list of data that contains the links that are not needed.  I want to apply the filter so that I can only get the data that starts with **/PIAimages**. How to apply the filter to do that?

```
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import csv 

    result = []
    response = requests.get("https://www.ikea.com/sa/en/catalog/products/00361049/")
    assert response.ok
    page = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

    for des in page.find_all('img'):
       image= des.get('src')
       print(image)
```

Expected output:

```
/PIAimages/0531313_PE647261_S1.JPG
/PIAimages/0513228_PE638849_S1.JPG
/PIAimages/0618875_PE688687_S1.JPG
/PIAimages/0325432_PE517964_S1.JPG
/PIAimages/0690287_PE723209_S1.JPG
/PIAimages/0513996_PE639275_S1.JPG
/PIAimages/0325450_PE517970_S1.JPG
```

Actual output:

```
/ms/img/header/ikea-logo.svg
/ms/en_SA/img/header/ikea-store.png
/ms/img/header/main_menu_shadow.gif
/sa/en/images/products/strandmon-wing-chair-beige__0513996_PE639275_S4.JPG
/PIAimages/0531313_PE647261_S1.JPG
/PIAimages/0513228_PE638849_S1.JPG
/PIAimages/0618875_PE688687_S1.JPG
/PIAimages/0325432_PE517964_S1.JPG
/PIAimages/0690287_PE723209_S1.JPG
/PIAimages/0513996_PE639275_S1.JPG
/PIAimages/0325450_PE517970_S1.JPG
/ms/img/static/loading.gif
/ms/img/static/stock_check_green.gif
/ms/img/ads/services/ways_to_shop/20172_otav20a_assembly_20x20.jpg
/ms/en_SA/img/icons/picking-with-delivery.jpg
/ms/img/ads/services/ways_to_shop/20172_otav24a_pickingdelivery_20x20.jpg
/sa/en/images/products/strandmon-wing-chair-beige__0739100_PH147003_S4.JPG
https://smetrics.ikea.com/b/ss/ikeaallnojavascriptprod/5/?c8=sa&pageName=nojavascript
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use If clause then append data into list.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

result = []
response = requests.get("https://www.ikea.com/sa/en/catalog/products/00361049/")
assert response.ok
page = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
for des in page.find_all('img'):
    image= des.get('src')
    if 'PIAimages' in image:
        result.append(image)

print(result)
```

OR use regular expression.This is much faster.

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

result = []
response = requests.get("https://www.ikea.com/sa/en/catalog/products/00361049/")
assert response.ok
page = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
for des in page.find_all('img', src=re.compile("PIAimages")):
    image= des.get('src')
    result.append(image)

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it faster and more concise to use css attribute = value selector with starts with operator. You specify the start substring for the src in the selector so only qualifying elements are returned.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get("https://www.ikea.com/sa/en/catalog/products/00361049/")
page = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")   
images = [item['src'] for item in page.select('img[src^=\/PIAimages]')]
print(images)
```